# Is it possible to translate a live feed in wordpress with Google Translate API or another tool?

Tags: wordpress, google-translate

I have a code that gives me a live news feed to embed in my wordpress website.

I want to translate this live feed and wonder how can I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a free and easy setup, you could use a plugin like this [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/google-language-translator/) or this [one](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gtranslate/).

If you want to start using Google Translate API, you could check this [guide](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text) to see how it works.

For a comparative of translation APIs, check this [link](https://blog.api.rakuten.net/top-10-best-translation-apis-google-translate-microsoft-translator-and-others/).